# Ado Update batch

Tags: ms-access, ado

I am having and issue using update batch. I have a loop that goes through a recordset updating values.  I have a minimum of 333 things in the batch. When it gets to the 254th item it bails. is there a limit to a batch.

```
On Error GoTo Err_cmdProcessAll

Dim cn              As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs              As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strTableName As String
Dim strSql As String

'
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

cn.Open "Provider=sqloledb; " & _
    "Data Source=" & "BLD-FS-SQLVS04\PRDINST4" & ";" & _
    "Initial Catalog=" & "HNFS_NetProv" & ";" & _
    "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
cn.CursorLocation = adUseServer

Dim strSortField As String
Dim additionalwhere As String




If cboValue = "pc3Claims" Then
    strTableName = "Seq3_PendedClaims_Ranked"
    strSortField = "DaysSinceReceivedClaim"
  '  additionalwhere = " AND (member_eligibility_ud Not Like '%Program%')
  strSql = "Select * " & _
        "FROM " & strTableName & _
        " WHERE (Complete Is Null) And (AssignedTo Is Null)" & additionalwhere & _
          " ORDER BY cast( " & strSortField & " as int )" & strSort

ElseIf cboValue = "pc3ContractAssignments" Then
    strSortField = "date"
    additionalwhere = ""
    strSql = "Select * " & _
        "FROM " & strTableName & _
        " WHERE (Complete Is Null) And (AssignedTo Is Null)" & additionalwhere & _
        " ORDER BY CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, [" & strSortField & "], 111), 121) " & strSort
End If

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
       Set .ActiveConnection = cn
        .Source = strSql

        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
       .Open
    End With
'make change to above to include
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim strAssignAssociate As String
Dim lngAllocAmt As Long
For i = 1 To ListView6.ListItems.Count
    If ListView6.ListItems(i).Checked Then
       strAssignAssociate = ListView6.ListItems(i).SubItems(1)
       Debug.Print strAssignAssociate
       lngAllocAmt = ListView6.ListItems(i).Text
       For j = 1 To lngAllocAmt
        Debug.Print rs.Fields("AssignedTo")
        rs.Fields("AssignedTo") = strAssignAssociate
               Debug.Print rs.Fields("AssignedTo")
        rs.MoveNext
       Next j
    End If
Next i
rs.UpdateBatch
MsgBox "All Finished", vbOKOnly, "Inventory Control"
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

Comment: I get the dreaded "too many rows were effected by the update. how do I get past this. BTW. this is a non keyed file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  I am using a non-keyed file.  I found that I had duplicates in the file.  this has been rectified and the above code works fine.